# How to call this onclick javascript function in my architecture

Tags: javascript, oop, architecture, extjs

I am using this article of architecture http://blog.extjs.eu/know-how/writing-a-big-application-in-ext/

In my one class of Dashboardgrid i have two functions are :

```
,linkRenderer : function (data, cell, record, rowIndex, columnIndex, store) {
        if  (data != null)  {
            return '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="this.resellerwindow(\'' +record.data.cityname+'\')">'+ data +'</a>';
        }
        return data;
    },
    resellerwindow : function (cityname) {
        // render the grid to the specified div in the page
        // resellergrid.render();
        resellerstore.load();
        wingrid.show(this);
    }
```

when the click event of linkrendrer function is called it gives error

```
this.resellerwindow is not a function
```

where and how should i put resellerwindow function ?

My ResellerDashBoard Class

```
Application.DashBoardGrid = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {
     border:false
    ,initComponent:function() {
        var config = {
            store:new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                // store configs
                autoDestroy: true,
                autoLoad :true,
                url: 'api/index.php?_command=getresellerscount',
                storeId: 'getresellerscount',
                // reader configs
                root: 'cityarray',
                idProperty: 'cityname',
                fields: [
                    {name: 'cityname'},
                    {name: 'totfollowup'},
                    {name: 'totcallback'},
                    {name: 'totnotintrested'},
                    {name: 'totdealsclosed'},
                    {name: 'totcallsreceived'},
                    {name: 'totcallsentered'},
                    {name: 'totresellerregistered'},
                    {name: 'countiro'},
                    {name: 'irotransferred'},
                    {name: 'irodeferred'}
                ]
            })
            ,columns: [
                {
                    id       :'cityname',
                    header   : 'City Name', 
                    width    : 120, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'cityname'
                },
                {
                    id       :'countiro',
                    header   : ' Total Prospect', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'countiro'
                },
                 {
                    id       :'irotransferred',
                    header   : 'Calls Transfered By IRO', 
                    height : 50,
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'irotransferred'
                },
                {
                    id       :'irodeferred',
                    header   : ' Calls Deferred By IRO', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'irodeferred'
                },
                {
                    id       :'totcallsentered',
                    header   : ' Total Calls Entered', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex : 'totcallsentered',
                    renderer : this.linkRenderer
                },
                {
                    id       :'totfollowup',
                    header   : ' Follow Up', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'totfollowup'
                },
                {
                    id       :'totcallback',
                    header   : ' Call Backs', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'totcallback'
                },
                {
                    id       :'totnotintrested',
                    header   : ' Not Interested', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'totnotintrested'
                },
                {
                    id       :'totdealsclosed',
                    header   : ' Deals Closed', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'totdealsclosed'
                },
                 {
                    id       :'totresellerregistered',
                    header   : ' Reseller Registered', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'totresellerregistered'
                }
            ]
          ,plugins :[]
          ,viewConfig :{forceFit:true}
          ,tbar :[]
          ,bbar :[]
          ,height : 350
          ,width : 1060
           ,title : 'Reseller Dashboard'

        }; // eo config object

        // apply config
        Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));

        Application.DashBoardGrid.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    } // eo function initComponent
    /** 
    * It is the renderer of the links of cell 
    * @param data  value of cell 
    * @param record  object of data has all the data of store and record.id is unique 
    **/
    ,linkRenderer : function (data, cell, record, rowIndex, columnIndex, store) {
        if  (data != null)  {
            return '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="DashBoardGrid.resellerwindow(\'' +record.data.cityname+'\')">'+ data +'</a>';
        }
        return data;
    },
    resellerwindow : function (cityname) {
        // render the grid to the specified div in the page
        // resellergrid.render();
        resellerstore.load();
        wingrid.show(this);

    }
    ,onRender:function() {
        // this.store.load();
        Application.DashBoardGrid.superclass.onRender.apply(this, arguments);
    } // eo function onRender
});

Ext.reg('DashBoardGrid', Application.DashBoardGrid);
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery as well?

Comment: well how could the resselerwindow function belong to the link dom object?

Comment: On click of linkdom object i want  resellerwindow function to be called

Answer (score 0):

Your scope is messed up, when the function in your `<a>` tag is called this does not point to your object where you defined the function but to your `<a>`-dom node.

It's pretty hard to call member functions from within a html fragment like the fragment returned by a grid renderer. I suggest you take a look at [Ext.grid.ActionColumn](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.ActionColumn) to solve this problem. When you look at the code in this column type you should be able to write your own column type that renders a link instead of an icon like the ActionColumn.

Another option is using my [Ext.ux.grid.ButtonColumn](https://github.com/Inventis/Ext.ux.grid.ButtonColumn) which doesn't render links but buttons in your grid.

more info on scope in ExtJS (and js in general):  http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:What_is_that_Scope_all_about

Comment: But i tried example action column but not getting how it work ?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.resellerwindow is not a function
```

because 'this', in the onclick function is in fact  a reference to the 'a' dom element;

In order to access the 'resellerwindow' function from the onclick handler, you need to make the function accessible from the global scope, where your handler is executed:

```
var globalObj = 
{
    linkRenderer : function (data, cell, record, rowIndex, columnIndex, store) 
    {
        if  (data != null)              
            return '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="globalObj.resellerwindow(\''  +record.data.cityname+'\')">'+ data +'</a>';        
        return data;
    },
    resellerwindow : function (cityname) 
    {
        // render the grid to the specified div in the page
        // resellergrid.render();
        resellerstore.load();
        wingrid.show(this);
    } 
}
```

so use the globalObj.resellerwindow(......);

Comment: I have updated question with my class please tell by what function name i can use this ?

Comment: I`m not a ext expert, so I may be wrong... but I think it should be Ext.grid.GridPanel... because you extend it...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this does not point to the class itself. Should you need to render the a element as a string instead of JavaScript object you will need to call a global function in which to call the resellerwindow function (after obtaining correct reference). However, I believe a much more efficient way would be to abandon the string and use JavaScript object instead. Then you can do something like the following:

```
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.onclick = this.resselerwindow;
```

If you use jQuery something like the following can be used:

```
return $("<a />").click(this.resselerwindow)[0];
```

Comment: look carefully , the return type is an html text, not the dom element... so it should be return $("<a />").click(this.resselerwindow)[0].outerHTML... but this (outerHTML) doesn`t work in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

instead of building and passing direct html, try these.

1. Create Anchor object

> { tag: 'a', 
>       href: '#', 
>       html: 'click me', 
>       onclick: this.resellerWindow    }

1. Make sure that, scope in linkRenderer is grid, by settings 'scope: this' in that column definition. So that this.resellerWindow refers to grid's function.
2. try returning created object.

Comment: ,linkRenderer : function (data, cell, record, rowIndex, columnIndex, store) {
        var tag={ 
            tag: 'a',
            href: '#', 
            html: data, 
            onclick: this.resellerwindow(record.data.cityname,cell.id) 
        };
        
     
        return tag;
    }
   ,resellerwindow : function (cityname,columndataindex) {
    
        var win = new Ext.Window({
            items:{
                xtype : 'ResellerGrid',
                'cityname' : cityname,
                'columndataindex' : columndataindex
             }
        });
        win.show();
    }

Comment: This what i tried but still saying that this.resellerwindow is not a function